# How to merge new features at later stage of model?

Tags: keras

I have training data in the form of numpy arrays, that I will use in ConvLSTM. 
Following are dimensions of array. 
`trainX = (5000, 200, 5)`  **where 5000 are number of samples. 200 is time steps per sample, and 8 is number of features per timestep.** (samples, timesteps, features).

out of these 8 features, 3 features remains the same throghout all timesteps in a sample (In other words, these features are directly related to samples). for example, day of the week, month number, weekday (these changes from sample to sample). To reduce the complexity, **I want to keep these three features separate from initial training set and merge them with the output of convlstm layer** before applying dense layer for classication (softmax activiation). e,g
Intial training set dimension would be `(7000, 200, 5)` and auxiliary input dimensions to be merged would be `(7000, 3)` --> because these 3 features are directly related to sample. How can I implement this using keras?

Following is my code that I write using Functional API, but don't know how to merge these two inputs.

```py
    #trainX.shape=(7000,200,5)
    #trainy.shape=(7000,4)
    #testX.shape=(3000,200,5)
    #testy.shape=(3000,4)
    #trainMetadata.shape=(7000,3)
    #testMetadata.shape=(3000,3)

    verbose, epochs, batch_size = 1, 50, 256
    samples, n_features, n_outputs = trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[2], trainy.shape[1]
    n_steps, n_length = 4, 50
    input_shape = (n_steps, 1, n_length, n_features)
    model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

    clstm1 = ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(1,3), activation='relu',return_sequences = True)(model_input)
    clstm1 = BatchNormalization()(clstm1)

    clstm2 = ConvLSTM2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(1,3), activation='relu',return_sequences = False)(clstm1)
    conv_output = BatchNormalization()(clstm2)

    metadata_input = Input(shape=trainMetadata.shape)
    merge_layer = np.concatenate([metadata_input, conv_output])

    dense = Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l=0.01))(merge_layer)
    dense = Dropout(0.5)(dense)
    output = Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax')(dense)


    model = Model(inputs=merge_layer, outputs=output)

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    history = model.fit([trainX, trainMetadata], trainy, validation_data=([testX, testMetadata], testy), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(testX, testy, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
    y = model.predict(testX)
```

but I am getting Value error at merge_layer statement. Following is the ValueError

```
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying can not be done using  the `Sequential` mode of Keras.

You need to use the Model class API [Guide to Keras Model](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/).

With this API you can build the complex model you are looking for

Here you have an example of how to use it: [How to Use the Keras Functional API for Deep Learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/keras-functional-api-deep-learning/)

Comment: I followed this tutorial, but I am facing problem or merging attributes. I am also editing the post with the solution I am trying. If you figure out, where I am doing wrong.